# C program to check whether a number is armstrong won't work

Tags: c

I am a beginner at C. This is my code to check whether a number is Armstrong but it says `not armstrong` for every number.

I really don't have anything else to stay but stackoverflow says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." Hence this extra line.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_digits(int num)
{
    int count;
    for (count = 0; num != 0; count++)
    {   
        num /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}

bool check_armstrong(int num, int num_length)
{ 
    int sum;
    int digit = 0;
    int temp_num = num; 
    for (int sum = 0; temp_num != 0;) 
    {
        digit = temp_num % 10; 
        temp_num /= 10; 
        sum += pow(digit, num_length); 
    }

    if (sum == num)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int input_num;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &input_num);
    
    if (check_armstrong(input_num, count_digits(input_num)))
    {
        printf("It is an armstrong number.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("It is not an armstrong number.");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically: please format your code properly, post a [mre] and and specifiy exactly both the expected and actual behavior.

Comment: Please always apply proper formatting to your code. That includes consistent indentation. It would make it rather obvious that there is some `{` missing.

Comment: You were missing a brace and the `sum` declared in the for loop shadows the one declared before it. If those issues are corrected it seems to work. https://godbolt.org/z/rc3fEYfve Best to not use `pow` for integer calculations though, it might not always work.

Comment: Apologies for the bad formatting. I have edited the code now. This is the first time I am posting something on stackoverflow.

Comment: "I really don't have anything else to stay but" That is completely wrong. You did not tell us what your program is supposed to do. What input do you provide, what output do you get, what do you expect? How do you compile and do you get any errors or warnings? Basically you did not even ask any question in the first version.

Comment: My bad -- new to Firefox 115 and scrollbar was hidden. The `main()` included is fine -- I just had to find it `:)` The code ended at the end of `bool check_armstrong(int num, int num_length)` on my display -- until the little-skinny scrollbar appeared.

Comment: Definition and code in various languages, including C, for checking can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number

Answer (score 2):

The reason your program fails is rather a subtle one:

In the `check_armstrong` function, you defined `sum` at the beginning of the function body with `int sum;` but you redefine another variable `sum` inside the `for` loop: `for (int sum = 0; temp_num != 0;) { ... }`. These are 2 separate variables, the second having its scope restricted to the `for` loop.  The computed value is hence lost as soon as the loop ends and the `sum` variable you compare to `num` is the initial one, which by the way is still uninitialized.  This explains the function failure and the behavior is actually undefined so the function output is unpredictable and anything else could happen.

Remove the `int` in the `for` loop: `for (sum = 0; temp_num != 0;)` or better initialize `sum` to `0` and use a different loop variable.

To avoid such mistakes, you should compile with all warnings enabled: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`. This let's the compiler complain about potential programming errors when code seems inconsistent or uses unusual contructions. In this case the compiler would report `for (int sum; ...)` as shadowing the `sum` variable already defined and `sum == num` has having undefined behavior because `sum` is uninitialized.

It is also recommended to use integer arithmetics instead of the `pow` function, or at least use `round()` before converting to `int` to avoid the implicit `double` to `int` conversion that truncates the fractional part.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int count_digits(int num) {
    int count;
    for (count = 0; num != 0; count++) {   
        num /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}

bool check_armstrong(int num, int num_length) { 
    int sum = 0;
    for (int temp_num = num; temp_num != 0; temp_num /= 10) {
        int digit = temp_num % 10; 
        sum += (int)round(pow(digit, num_length)); 
    }
    return sum == num;
}

int main(void) {
    int input_num;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &input_num) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (check_armstrong(input_num, count_digits(input_num))) {
        printf("%d is an Armstrong number.\n", input_num);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not an Armstrong number.\n", input_num);
    }

    getchar();  // read the pending newline
    getchar();  // wait for more input so the program output stays visible
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However, the code works for every armstrong number except 153. I don't understand why.

Comment: @Starblaze: it works on my macbook for 153 too.  It is possible that `pow()` give a result that is gets rounded down incorrectly on some platforms.  I would recommend using integer arithmetics and/or use `sum += (int)round(pow(digit, num_length));` instead of the implicit `double` to `int` conversion that truncates the fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

Inside check_armstrong function you should remove int keyword before sum variable inside for loop variable as it is already decalared. The code will work fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for informing. Appreciate that.